# Selenium: How to track DOM manipulation to find visibility of an element?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, dom

Is there a possibility of watching a webpage for events like: an element has been made visible?

And is this possible using selenium?

For example, If I define a timeline for watching a webpage from startTime to endTime. From startTime to endTime, different webpage events could be captured, which includes dom manipulations ( for example: html element has got added and been made visible ). Once endTime is reached, I would iterate over the list of events and I could validate a particular event has occurred or not.

In my case, I would like to find out if an html element has been made visible or not.

The usual way to find out is to use webdriver's API to check visibility of an element, with some timeout.

But, I would like to capture different events and have some callbacks, thereby validating that some expected event has occurred.

[UPDATE]: Do we have a support for [MutationObserver](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-track-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobse) in Selenium?

Comment: It is tough to understand your exact requirement with a verbose text along with generic actions and without any tried out code. Can you update us your manual steps please?

Comment: I haven't tried out code, but facing a scenario where we are not able to locate a htmlelement within a timeout, even though visually we saw that htmlelement becoming visible. Looking for alternatives to track dom manipulation, just found about MutationObserver. now checking if selenium has an API related to MutationObserver

Comment: Without any tried out code & error stack trace, it's pretty difficult to guess what's wrong happening out there and to narrow down to a remedy. Yeah, `MutationObserver` does have a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: are there events like "New element inserted in DOM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192258/selenium-are-there-events-like-new-element-inserted-in-dom)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample of what you can do:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // how many seconds
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(myPage.getButton()));
```

For more sophisticated things you can provide your own `Function` for `WebDriverWait`, i.e:

```
wait.until(o -> {
    return driver.getWindowHandles().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).get(tabNo);
});
```

Comment: `ExpectedConditions` use polling rather than detect DOM events. So if an element changes its state and then quickly changes back, I can miss that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use explicit wait as shown in the [WebDriver Documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

The `ExpectedConditions` class provides many useful element states such as `ElementToBeVisible`, `ElementToBeClickable`, etc.

That should do the trick.

Comment: `ExpectedConditions` use polling rather than detect events. So if an element changes its state and then quickly changes back, I can miss that.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't support events, so you probably should move to another tool like [puppetter](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which seems to support events. That said, it's still possible to record events with a script injection by storing all the events in a variable in the page:

```java
jse.executeScript(
  "var window.__events = [];" +
  "new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {" +
  "    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {" +
  "        window.__events.push(mutation);" +
  "    });" +
  "})).takeRecords();");
```

Then simply return the list:

```java
Object events = jse.executeScript("return window.__events;");
```