# How to detect when a div's value is updated with selenium

Tags: python, java, html, selenium, dom

I'm gathering data from a website with selenium. There is a parent div which has 30 children divs. At random time intervals a value is updated and stored at the first child while the last one is removed (essentially keeping track of the 30 last numbers each moment).
Is there a way to detect when a new value is added? (I want to store them in order)
Note that I can get the same value twice or more times.

I'm mostly trying not to compare values just detect when that part of the DOM changes.

Edit: I am writing in Python but found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

I do not want to write a selenium extension as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192258/selenium-are-there-events-like-new-element-inserted-in-dom), is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this. First you run javascript like this example :

```
javaScript = "document.getElementsByName('username')[0].click();"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```

And inside the js you use the [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) at the node of interest.